# mysql print data between dates

Tags: mysql, date, dayofweek

Hi I have below mysql table
mysql> select * from test_raw limit 5;

**dt**  **admin**  **balance**

2013-08-02  AR    8734736
 2013-08-02  AZ        190
 2013-08-02  BA       7007
 2013-08-02  BE       7125
 2013-08-02  BG       5189

I want to print data of a week considering that week starts from Thursday to Wednesday and I want to run query on Monday. Please suggest a way to print this data, is there a way to give date range between now( ) -11 to -4 day ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from sccp_raw 
where dt between curdate() - interval 11 day 
         and curdate() - interval 4 day
limit 5;
```

Comment: Hi, Can you please look into this:  
"http://stackoverflow.com/q/18892417/2761031"  
similar question but bit more complexity